# proxmox lxc container failed to start

Tags: lxc, zfs, proxmox

When I try to run my `lxc` container, I get:

```
lxc-start: 100: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 751 No such file or directory - Failed to receive the container state
lxc-start: 100: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 371 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: 100: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 373 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
lxc-start: 100: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 375 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

My `lxc` config:

```
#WEBSERVER
arch: amd64
cores: 1
hostname: poseidon
memory: 2048
net0: name=eth0,bridge=vmbr0,gw=192.168.0.1,hwaddr=66:79:16:C7:C3:51,ip=192.168.0.12/24,type=veth
onboot: 1
ostype: debian
#rootfs: local-zfs:subvol-100-disk-1,size=30G
rootfs: local-zfs:subvol-100-disk-1,size=30G
searchdomain: 192.168.0.1
swap: 512

root@cronos:/etc/pve/lxc# pvesm list local-zfs --
local-zfs:subvol-100-disk-1 subvol 32212254720 100
local-zfs:subvol-101-disk-1 subvol 8589934592 101
local-zfs:vm-102-disk-1       raw 161061273600 102
local-zfs:vm-103-disk-1       raw 34359738368 103

root@cronos:/etc/pve/lxc# zfs list
NAME                           USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                         30.6G  3.48T   104K  /rpool
rpool/ROOT                    4.17G  3.48T    96K  /rpool/ROOT
rpool/ROOT/pve-1              4.17G  3.48T  4.17G  /
rpool/data                    17.9G  3.48T    96K  /rpool/data
rpool/data/subvol-100-disk-1  4.87G  25.1G  4.87G  /rpool/data/subvol-100-disk-1
rpool/data/subvol-101-disk-1   859M  7.16G   859M  /rpool/data/subvol-101-disk-1
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1      5.68G  3.48T  5.68G  -
rpool/data/vm-103-disk-1      6.47G  3.48T  6.47G  -
rpool/swap                    8.50G  3.49T  3.99G  -
```

This situation occurred after my `zpool` disappeared, and I re-import it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with AppArmor in stretch-proposed-updates. I fixed this by inserting this line into `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb http://download.proxmox.com/debian/pve stretch pve-no-subscription`

Keep in mind that this is not the best fix for a production server. [Proxmox states](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Package_Repositories):

> It can be used for testing and non-production use. It is not
>   recommended to run on production servers, as these packages are not
>   always heavily tested and validated.